# What is length of segmented part by circle from $x$ axis

Tags: circles

A circle intersects at point $A(x_1, 0)$ and $B(x_2,0)$ at $x$-axis. If the equation the circle is $x^2+y^2+2gx+2fy+c = 0$. Then what is the length of $AB$?

Comment: Why not just $|x_1-x_2|$?

Comment: Do you mean the  length of the **arc** $AB$? What have you tried?

Comment: No, Sir.The length of segmented part of X axis.

Comment: Are you meant to express this length in terms of $f$, $g$ and $c$?

Comment: Absolutely Sir. Sorry for the delay.